# How to write function which change button color

Tags: swift, background, background-color

I have a small problem. I created a short quiz app, and when we choose the answer the answer is green. I need a function that will change all buttons to the basic color, blue

Comment: where is your code?

Answer (score 3):

First you should have array with references for your buttons. If you use interface builder, you can create outlet collection

```
@IBOutlet var buttons: [UIButton]!
```

Then, when button is pressed, change color for each button depending on if element is equal to sender of action for button pressed event

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    for button in buttons {
        button.backgroundColor = button == sender ? .green : .blue
    }
}
```